# Repair old garage workbench

Tags: wood, woodworking, garage, table

I have this old garage workbench that seems very sturdy

[image]

The wood is OK, I could replace the door.

But the surface's corner has cracking like this:

[image]

This is done from previous owner. I would like to fix it somehow. What is that thin strip of wood outside? It seems like it's harden by some chemical process (not paint or maybe...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like hardboard, "High density fibreboard" to use its full name.

AKA "Masonite"(tm)

Comment: Any suggestions for how to fix it?  -)